# Conversion of symbolic expression to numeric one for use in quad - use lambdify?

Tags: scipy, sympy, numerical-methods, numerical-integration, quad

I want to convert an expression containing symbolic variables to a numeric one so that the expression may be subsequently used in an integration method 'quad'.

```
import numpy 
import math as m
import scipy
import sympy

#define constants                                                                                                                                                                    
gammaee = 5.55e-6
MJpsi = 3.096916
alphaem = 1/137
lambdasq = 0.09
Ca = 3
qOsq = 2

def qbarsq(qsq):
    return (qsq+MJpsi**2)/4


def xx(qbarsq, w):
    return 4*qbarsq/(4*qbarsq-MJpsi**2+w**2)

from sympy import *
x,NN,a,b,ktsq,qbarsq,w = symbols('x NN a b ktsq qbarsq w')


def xg(a,b,NN,ktsq,x):
    return NN*(x**(-a))*(ktsq**b)*exp(sqrt((16*Ca/9)*log(1/x)*log((log(ktsq/lambdasq))/(log(qOsq/lambdasq)))))


#prints symbolic derivative of xg                                                                                                                                                    
def func(NN,a,b,x,ktsq):
    return (-x*diff(log(xg(a,b,NN,ktsq,x)),x))

#print(func(NN,a,b,x,ktsq))                                                                                                                                                          

#prints symbolic expression for Rg                                                                                                                                                   
def Rg(NN,a,b,ktsq,x):
     return 2**(2*func(NN,a,b,x,ktsq)+3)/sqrt(m.pi)*gamma(func(NN,a,b,x,ktsq)+5/2)/gamma(func(NN,a,b,x,ktsq)+4)
#print(Rg(NN,a,b,ktsq,x))

#prints symbolic expression for Fktsq                                                                                                                                                
def FktsqDeriv(NN,a,b,x,ktsq):
    return diff(Rg(NN,a,b,ktsq,x)*xg(a,b,NN,ktsq,x),ktsq)
#print(FktsqDeriv(NN,a,b,x,ktsq))      

def Fktsq1(qbarsq,ktsq,NN,a,b,w):
    return FktsqDeriv(NN,a,b,x,ktsq).subs(x,4*qbarsq/(4*qbarsq-MJpsi**2+w**2))

#print(Fktsq1(qbarsq,ktsq,NN,a,b,w))


# symbolic expression for fA                                                                                                                                                         
def fA(ktsq,qbarsq,NN,a,b,w):
    return Fktsq1(qbarsq,ktsq,NN,a,b,w)*1/(qbarsq)*1/(qbarsq+ktsq)
print(fA(qbarsq,ktsq,NN,a,b,w))
```

The code runs up to here and returns the correct function `fA`. `fA` is a symbolic valued expression which I want to pass onto quad to perform an integration over (over `ktsq`)

```
import scipy.integrate.quadrature as sciquad
def integrated_f(qbarsq,NN,a,b,w):
    return sciquad(fA,1,(w**2-MJpsi**2)/4, args=(qbarsq, NN, a, b, w))
```

My understanding is that this fails because the first argument of `quad`, i.e. the function, is of symbolic type and not numeric (=floating point) required for quad. How to make the function numeric and thus allow me to perform the integration? I've tried `.subs` and `lambdify` function but couldn't get it to work. The former seems to work only if  numbers are supplied (i.e set `NN=0.1` for example which I don't want to do) and I tried the following for lambdify

```
def test(ktsq):
    return fA(ktsq,qbarsq,NN,a,b,w)

f = lambdify(((qbarsq,NN,a,b,w),), test(ktsq))
#print(f(1,2,3,4,5))
```

but this gave error about number of positional arguments when I uncommented the print to check if all was working.

`TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use lambdify. The first argument of `lambdify` is a tuple of symbols, not a tuple of tuples as in your code. The second argument is a SymPy expression. Example:

```
from sympy import *
a, b, c, d, e = symbols('a b c d e')
expr = a*b + 2*c + d/e
f = lambdify((a, b, c, d, e), expr)
print(f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))   # prints 8.8
```

In your case, this would look like

```
expr = fA(qbarsq, ktsq, NN, a, b, w)
f = lambdify((qbarsq, ktsq, NN, a, b, w), expr, "mpmath")
```

Here mpmath is chosen as the backend because it can evaluate Gamma function that your expression contains. Otherwise, it would probably be faster to use "numpy" backend option. See [more on lambdify](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html).

```
print(f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))  #  (-4757.21371513605 + 58978.7828908493j)
```

How it works with `quad`... depends on whether you get real or complex numbers. When they are real, you can integrate with `scipy.integrate.quad`:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
quad(f, 3, 4, args=(2, 3, 4, 5, 6))[0]
```

returns `30049812.82526324`.

If they are complex, SciPy's `quad` will be unhappy with `mpc` type which it doesn't understand. But `mpmath` has its own `quad`, so use that instead:

```
import mpmath as mp
mp.quad(lambda x: f(2, x, 3, 4, 5, 6), [1, 3])
```

returns `mpc(real='7170810.3848631922', imag='-192389955826656.31')`. Here  [1, 3] is the interval of integration.

Comment: Thanks! Did you manage to get it to work with my example? Removing those extraneous brackets that I had in the first argument I get an error that I could not understand: `AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'log'` Any comments about that?

Comment: I used the def declarations because my expressions are involved in differentiation which generate very long expressions. To reuse them and not instead call them as a function seems inefficient. Isn't the indenting correct? I'm not sure the meaning of 'Mul' - A search on here refers to a clash of numpy and scipy namespaces but I did not write anything that would cause such a clash, as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed. Given numeric arguments, can I now pass this `f` onto `sciquad`? In my attempt at integration in second part of my OP, I replaced `fA` with `f(ktsq,qbarsq,NN,a,b,w)` where `f = lambdify((ktsq,qbarsq,NN,a,b,w), expr, "mpmath")`. I understand the integration is done over the first argument. But this gave me an mpf error.  What is wrong with this?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for asking too much but what happens if I wanted to multiply my `f`with,say, an interpolating function depending on the integration variable? The error is that `ValueError: object arrays are not supported`. If it's better I can accept your answer and post this as another question. thanks!

Comment: I don't have time to answer now, so a separate question makes more sense: someone else may be able to answer.

Comment: Ok thanks! here is the question if you are able to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569794/how-to-extend-numerical-integration-method-to-allow-integration-over-an-object-a